# How to grow div so that rounded border contains child border and content?

Tags: css

I have a div with a rounded border that has one or more children of indeterminate size with rectangle borders. The border(s) of the children are partially rendered outside of the border of the parent. I want the parent div to grow far enough that it's rounded border completely contains the children and their borders.

```css
#parent {
  display: flex;
  width: fit-content;
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#child1 {
  border: 2px solid green;
}

#child2 {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child1">child 1</div>
  <div id="child2">child 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: add padding to the parent ?